# Variable doesn't get updated after function processes

Tags: java, android

I'm building this calculator app with two textviews (one for the formula and one for the result). Now the result after calculations is stored in a variable called result which is left empty by default. But when I run it, after the function executes, everything works but the result variable still remains an empty string. Please help me.

### ScientificCalculator.java

```
 int prevAnswer = 0;
TextView formulascreen;
TextView resultscreen;
String formuladisplay = "";
String resultdisplay = "";
String result = "";
String operator;

public void onClickEquals(View view) {

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Equals to: " + String.valueOf(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    if (operator == "+" || operator == "-" || operator == "x" || operator == "÷") {

        getResult();
        updateresultdisplay();

    }

}

private boolean getResult() {

    if (operator == "") return false;

    String[] operation = formuladisplay.split(Pattern.quote(operator));

    if (operation.length < 2) return false;

    result = String.valueOf(res.format(simpleOp(operation[0], operation[1], operator)));

    return true;

}

public double simpleOp(String a, String b, String op) {

    switch (op) {

        case "+":
            return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);

        case "-":
            return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);

        case "x":
            return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);

        case "÷":
            return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);

        default:
            return -1;

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: in Java you don't compare strings using `==` but using `equals`. To check for empty string use `isEmpty()`.

Comment: @cyroxis Tip: `[mcve]` will autocomplete to the link you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two result variables: `result` and `resultdisplay`. The calculation code updates `result`, but within `updateresultdisplay()` you use display the contents of the (unchanging) `resultdisplay`.

So you just need to update `updateresultdisplay()` to

```
private void updateresultdisplay() {
    resultscreen.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I tried it and its returning result as an empty string again :(.

Comment: Apparently, I found out that the "if" function in the onClickEquals() method doesn't run.

Comment: Where should onClickEquals() be triggered from? Can you post all the code?

Comment: No need. Fixed it. Just had to remove the stupid "if" statement and also made the change suggested by Thomas Kläger. :). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @DayemSaeed in `onClickEquals` you are comparing `operator == "+"`, which is a comparison for the same string object. You should compare strings with the `equals(..)` method: `operator.equals("+")`, which compares for the same content (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)